# jwt.sign() everytime added token to the previous token

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose, jwt

Everytime when i am doing post request to the authenticate route its, adding token to the previous token. I cant find the reason of this problem

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/user");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const config = require("../config/data");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//Registration route
router.post("/register",(req,res)=>{
    let date=new Date();
    let newUser = new User({
        name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password,
        role:"User",
        isActive:true,
        created:date,
        updatedToken:"JWT"

    });
    User.addUser(newUser,(err,user)=>{
        if(err){
            res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to register user'});
          } else {
            res.json({success: true, msg:'User registered'});
          }
    });


});

//Authentication route
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.getUser(email, (err, user) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
      }

      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
          let payload={
            name:user.name,
            email:user.email,
            role:user.role,
            deleted:user.deleted,
            isActive:user.isActive,
            created:user.created,
            updatedToken:user.updatedToken,
          };

          let token=jwt.sign(payload,config.secret)

          User.saveToken(email,token,(err,success)=>{
            if(err) return err;
            console.log("Success");
            res.json({
              success: true,
              token: token
            });
          }); 


        } else {
          return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Wrong password'});
        }
      });
    });
  });
//   router.use(function(req, res, next) {

//       // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
//       var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

//       // decode token
//       if (token) {

//         // verifies secret and checks exp
//         jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {      
//           if (err) {
//             return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });    
//           } else {
//             // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
//             req.decoded = decoded;    
//             next();
//           }
//         });

//       } else {

//         // if there is no token
//         // return an error
//         return res.status(403).send({ 
//             success: false, 
//             message: 'No token provided.' 
//         });

//       }
//     });

//     // Dashboard
// router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
//   res.json({user: req.user});
// });

module.exports = router;
```

> And this is Schema and functions

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const config = require("../config/data");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    role:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    deleted:{
        type:Date,
        default:null,

    },
    isActive:{
        type:Boolean,
        required:true
    },
    created:{
        type:Date,
        required:true
    },
    updatedToken:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});

let User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema,'Users');


module.exports.getUser = function(username, callback){
    let query = {email: username}
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save(callback);
    });
    });
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, (err, isMatch) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
module.exports.saveToken = function(username,token,callback){
    let query = {email:username};
    let updateToken={updatedToken:token};
    User.findOneAndUpdate(query,updateToken,callback);
}
module.exports.generateToken=function(payload,secret){
    let token = jwt.sign(payload,secret,{
        expiresIn: 604800
    })
    return token;
}
```

> This is server

```
const express = require ("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("./config/data");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");

const route = require("./routes/users");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

let options = {
    useMongoClient: true,
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE, 
    reconnectInterval: 500, 
    poolSize: 10,
    bufferMaxEntries: 0
  };

mongoose.connect(config.database,options);

let db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
 console.log( `DB connected ${new Date()}...`);
});


app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send("Works aziz");
});

app.use("/users",route);


app.listen(config.port,()=>{
    console.log(`Server running ${config.port}...`);
});
```

I need that,if user doing post request to authenticate route, it must generate token and give it to variable token,not to concatenate everytime when user doing post request. 
Thank you very much!!!!!!

Comment: Try: findOneAndUpdate(query, {$set: updateToken}, callback)

Comment: I have tried to do, but problem comes from jwt.sign() method,let token should be created everytime when user doing post request, and take a value of jwt.sign() method, but it takes all previous post requests values and concatenating all of them. Thanks for answer))))))

Comment: Is this a public project that can be shared? I'd love to clone it and try since I seemed to not being able to reproduce :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the error is with `updatedToken:user.updatedToken,` inside the payload. When you first register it's `JWT`, because that's what you set it to in the registration controller. E.g. with real values

```
let payload={
  name: "testuser",
  email: "test@example.com",
  role: "user",
  deleted: false,
  isActive: true,
  created: 2017-11-26,
  updatedToken: "JWT",
};
```

After the first authentication, `user.updatedToken` gets updated with the token you make in `saveToken()`. That's *ey...* something.

After the second authentication you are adding the long JWT token (*ey...*) inside the payload:

```
let payload={
  name: "testuser",
  email: "test@example.com",
  role: "user",
  deleted: false,
  isActive: true,
  created: 2017-11-26,
  updatedToken: "ey1232abc456...",
};
```

This is the payload for the new token that gets saved to `user.updatedToken`. You are saving the old token in the new token.

So I'm pretty sure `updatedToken` inside the payload has to go.

Comment: Thank you very much. Today my birthday and this is the best gift,thanks a lot))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))